# Get Specific Lists from SharePoint site using RestAPI

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want to fetch desired lists from a SharePoint Site using RestAPI. I am able to get all the Lists from SharePoint Site but I want to fetch only 3-4 desired lists. Is there any filter or query to do it using REST API? (Note: I am not referring to list items. I want to filter the LISTS in the SharePoint site). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters like this :

/_api/Web/Lists/?$filter=IsCatalog eq false

/_api/Web/Lists/?$filter=Hidden eq false

Comment: I have tried both of these filters. What worked best for me was using filter by the BaseType. Thanks for your help Sachchin.